# How to use blueprints in Azure functions v2 for python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

In looking at the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=wsgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators#blueprints) What do blueprints offer that just importing doesn't?

Here are some points that are unclear:

- It says to have a file called `http_blueprint.py` in which you'd define some routes but it just looks like the regular http trigger but the decorator is a `bp.route` instead of an `app.route`.  Are these also app.functions since the main file has 2 decorators per `def`?
- Does everything in the blueprint have to be an http trigger or is that just an example that they used?
- Can you have multiple blueprint files or are we limited to the single one?

Comment: Hey Dean - I've answered some of these questions on the MS Q&A post you've made: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1076156/index.html

Comment: @MikeUrnunMSFT You **did indeed** answer OP's question on **whether** it's possible to have multiple blueprint files. However, I believe that OP (and us too) wonder **how** to do so. I've failed finding any docs for the `register_functions()` method. The only provided example is for a single file. I question that it's possible until proven wrong (humorously, of course). Would you care to post a sample showing how to do it?

Comment: @KonradViltersten fwiw I abandoned their new v2 model/framework. After really struggling with some intricacies of the new syntax I found (I forget the specifics) that the performance was much worse too.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Abandoned in favor of what? I wasn't aware there were any alternatives, to be honest.

Comment: @KonradViltersten just sticking with V1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example of repo structure.

```
project
│   file001.py
│   file002.py
│   function_app.py
│   README.md
│   host.json
│   local.settings.json
```

file001.py:

```
import azure.function as func
import json
    
bp01 = func.Blueprint()
@bp01.route(route="route01")
def method01(req:func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpRequest:
    return func.HttpResponse (
        json.dumps({
        'version': 1
        })
    )
```

file002.py:

```
import azure.function as func
import json
    
bp02 = func.Blueprint()
@bp02.route(route="route02")
def method02(req:func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpRequest:
    return func.HttpResponse (
        json.dumps({
        'version': 2
        })
    )
```

This is how you register more than one blueprint in function_app.py:

```
import azure.functions as func 
from file001.py import bp01
from file002.py import bp02

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS) 

app.register_functions(bp01)
app.register_functions(bp01)
```

My guess blueprints are useful when you want separation of concerns but I don't know for certain.
The most confusing part to me was that the main methods from the two blueprints must have a unique name otherwise the azure function will get confused and not show neither.